# Can flume source act as a jms consumer

Tags: flume

I have just started looking into flume for writing messages to hdfs using the hdfs sink. I am wondering if flume source can act as a jms consumer for my message broker.

Does flume provide integration with message broker. 
Or do i need to write a custom jms client that will push messages to a flume source.

Comment: Update: I configured my agents with the flume jms source-hdfs sink and it addresses the integration with the message broker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flume 1.3 does not provide JMS source out of the box. However, it seems that such component will be shipped with the next version, Flume 1.4: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLUME-924.

Meanwhile you can get the source code of this new component [here](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=flume.git;a=tree;f=flume-ng-sources/flume-jms-source;h=881a91d4594b6eedbf4b6a153ac4fa8f3fed3e59;hb=trunk) and build it. AFAIK, Flume 1.4 does not break its interfaces, so probably the component will work with 1.3 as well.

Comment: Just wanted to update that i used the flume jms source to integrate with the broker.

Comment: @Integrator: Can you please out the flume conf of how to use JMS source, it will be of great help.

Comment: Flume documentation contains example: http://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#jms-source

Comment: @GlobalWarrior the link provided by Dmitry has details. The conf is too big to add as a comment. I can add it as an answer if you have a question for this.

Comment: @Integrator: I think i figured out the issue, I was missing a jar in libext. Thanks for help